# Are there more cost efficient ways to measure API response times from different locations?

Tags: node.js, performance, time, httprequest, response

I'm trying to find a server closest to a site. To check I get one of their APIs and check how long it takes for the API to respond. I am not the owner of the API and the site uses Cloudflare so looking at the site's IP will just give me a Cloudflare server.

Right now to determine the closest server location I'm taking one of their APIs that returns non-cached data and averaging the response time using date.now and fetch (I'm requesting the API every 20-30 seconds so I'm not stressing it); this works but, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to find a server location closer to the site, **are there any services that can test API response times by location?**

**At the moment of writing this I've gone through 5 different VPS'** and am at a 250-260ms response time (averaged). I was thinking of using proxies or a VPN but, there is a delay from my PC reaching  where the server's location.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Software rec questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: @user16217248 I'm looking for services or methods in general to find the latency of an API based on different locations, I'm not really looking for software specifically, I'm looking for a way to cost effectively check the ms delay on an api based on location.